# How to get the sum of foreign key table as a value in the primary table row in a select statement

Tags: sql, select

How to get the sum of foreign key table as a value in the primary table row in a select statement?

Consider table 1:

```
id(PK)   name    description
-----------------------------

 1       test1      desc1
 2       test2      desc2
```

Table 2 is:

```
id(FK)    value
-----------------
 1         5
 1         6
 2         7
 2         8
```

The result for the SQL select statement should be like

```
id     name   desc    sum(value)
----------------------------------
 1     test1  desc1        11
```

Comment: homeworks? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select 
  t.*, 
  ( select 
      sum(tt.value) 
    from table2 tt 
    where tt.id = t.id) sum_value
from table1
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way:

```
select p.id, p.name, p.description, sum(f.value)
from p join f on f.id = p.id
group by p.id, p.name, p.description
```

Or an alternative is to explicitly group the child values before joining (not sure if this syntax is correct for systems other than Oracle):

```
select p.id, p.name, p.description, fgroup.valuesum
from p join (select id,sum(value) valuesum from f group by id) fgroup
     on p.id = fgroup.id
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.name, T1.description, SUM(T2.Value)
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.name, T1.description
```

It might be worth reviewing the [basics of JOINs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) if this sort of query is giving you trouble.